# Ant-Contrib <foreach> task if a file present

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

In below code, abc-1.1.2.jar file present under the  `${webapps.dir}/App.ear/App.war/WEB-INF/lib/` folder.

```
<foreach target="updateApp" param="detectedApp">
    <path>
        <dirset dir="${webapps.dir}">
            <present targetdir="${webapps.dir}">
                <!-- All Web apps should have this folder containing abcd-*.jar -->
                <mapper type="regexp"
                    from="^(.*)/abcd([0-9.-]*)\.jar$$"
                    to="\1/abcd\2.jar"/>
            </present>
        </dirset>
    </path>
</foreach>
```

Comment: I have tried this too <mapper type="regexp" from="^(.*)/abcd([0-9.-]*)jar$$" to="\0"/>

Comment: `<dirset>` only matches directories, but the `<mapper>` is trying to match `.jar` files. What do you want `detectedApp` to be each time `<foreach>` calls `updateApp`?

Comment: I would like to get     ${webapps.dir}/App.ear/App.war as     updaeApp param value.

Comment: When I use <fileset>, ${webapps.dir}/App.ear/App.war/WEB-INF/lib/abce-1.1.2.jar as detectedApp param value. But I need ${webapps.dir}/App.ear/App.war as detectedApp param value.